# Pushed commits into repo, but repo on server contains no files

Tags: git, unix, version-control

My usage of git has mostly been through an IDE to date and I'm having a bit of a nightmare with what I thought would be an easy thing.

On the remote server I have gitolite running which seems to be working fine, my local machine can connect to the server and perform simple tasks.

I have a repo on the server with the same name as the repo on my local however the local repo was created a long time before the server version.

After a lot of reading on SO it was recommended to clone the remote then push to the server. So:

```
$ git clone ***server***:***repo***
Cloning into ***repo***...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

When I do this I get an encouraging message:

```
$ git push origin master
Counting objects: 4070, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3737/3737), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4070/4070), 15.16 MiB | 588 KiB/s, done.
Total 4070 (delta 867), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ***server***:***repo***.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
$
```

All looks good... **however the files are not on the server?**

Should I merge, what about rebase... this is where my knowledge completely falls apart.
I've tried to read the [git-scm](http://git-scm.com/documentation) documentation but I have to be honest.. it's way over my head and this seems like it should be such a simple thing to do.

Comment: I don't get. Why are you cloning from remote, from where did you get that information? Why aren't you just adding the remote repo reference with `git remote add` to your local and then doing a push?

Comment: `warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.` is your key.

Comment: maybe this was wrong, I read a lot of conflicting info, now I have all files on my local, none on remote, perhaps 2 repos on my local... I'm so confused.. that's why I'm asking.... thanks for the response

Comment: the only files on the server of any size are in the 'pack' directory which means nothing to me sadly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The server only contains a *bare* repository, i.e. **no** checkout. The files are only stored in the `objetcs/` directory and the `pack` files you mention. What you can do to verify that the files are indeed there, is e.g. to create a new clone from the server on your local machine. Alternatively, on the server, you can do a

```
git ls-tree -r master
```

which should give you a list of all the files along with their mode and hashes.

**EDIT**: You'll want to read the chapter about [Git on the server in the Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server) book.

Comment: Correct. Also, it *must* be a bare repository as you're not allowed to push to branches being checked out.

Comment: nice! yes they are there!! what can I do with them now?

Comment: @Alex could you elaborate your question a bit. It's a repo. What do you expect to do with them?

Comment: What do you mean by *what can I do with them now*??? The repository is on your server, and you can push and pull from it, collaborating with others. What more do you want?

Comment: @eis I was kind of expecting to have a repo full of files which could be accessed? like on my local?

Comment: @Alex that's not how it works. If you want the files out of it, you'll have to do a checkout/clone. The files are only there in the internal repo format. That's what it means to have a `bare` repository, a repository that you can push to. Like said previously, you cannot push to branches that are checked out = having the actual files in the file system.